# $I(X_1 \cap X_2)=\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

How to prove $I(X_1 \cap X_2)=\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$?

Clearly $\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)} \subseteq I(X_1 \cap X_2)$

But for $f \in I(X_1 \cap X_2)$ $f(x)=0 \forall x\in X_1 \cap X_2$.

how to show $f \in  \sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}$?

Comment: Where $X_i$ are...?

Comment: Have you looked into Hilbert's Nullstellensatz? It seems quite related, and if the theorem itself cannot be directly applied, then the proof definitely can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose $X_i=V(\mathfrak a_i)$, where $\mathfrak a_i$ are ideals in a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field. Then $$\sqrt{I(X_1)+I(X_2)}=\sqrt{\sqrt{\mathfrak a_1}+\sqrt{\mathfrak a_2}}=\sqrt{\mathfrak a_1+\mathfrak a_2}.$$ On the other side, $$I(X_1\cap X_2)=I(V(\mathfrak a_1)\cap V(\mathfrak a_2))=I(V(\mathfrak a_1+\mathfrak a_2))=\sqrt{\mathfrak a_1+\mathfrak a_2}.$$